# Is it possible to run Skype on my NAS or DD-WRT?

Tags: skype, nas, dd-wrt, voip

Ok so here is my setup:

- Qnap NAS > TS-210
- Gigabit router/switch with DD-WRT (big-generic)
- multiple PC's
- 1 usb-to-phone box > [Trust ST-1200 Internet Phone Station](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=14485) (this is pretty old...)
- 1 phone (cordless landline)

The usb-to-phone box is currently connected to my main workstation, and I have a little program called SkypeMate running. This enabled me to receive and make Skype-to-Skype or Skype-to-Phone calls with my landline phone. (cordless, so I can walk around).

But, since this workstation is not always on, and my router and nas basically are, is there a way to connect my phone to either one of them and be always online on skype?
I realize Skype is not open-source, and they don't have 'headless' clients. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

BTW, I mainly use Skype to call relatives in other countries, as local landline and mobilephone plans are much more expensive when it comes to international calls.

Thanks!

Comment: The exact model number of your 'USB-to-phone' box may be key in answering your question.  Could you edit your question to include it?

Comment: Which QNAP NAS?

Comment: edited question to provide models.

Answer (score 0):

Skype does not run on either ARMv5TE (NAS) or MIPS (router), so no. You will need either a ARMv6 or x86 device for it.